# TextView with a long text

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I am trying to make simple activity which contains a TextView only with a long text. I have used a `ScrollView` for the same. It always gives a `NullPointerException` error.

Here is the XML

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the code:

```
public class About extends Activity {

private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    tv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

}
```

Here is @string/about:

```
VISION
```

India is the fourth largest energy consumer in the world, yet, 83% of its demand in crude oil is met from imports rather than domestic production. Inflation due to prices of imported oil has put pressure on the government to engage in a desperate search for energy sources and security. We have so far been unable to bridge the gap between demand and supply in this crucial sector. The lynchpin of stability and growth to achieve energy security by 2030 lies with reducing dependence on overseas energy, and India is still far from this laudable and ambitious goal.

PETROFIESTA 2013 is the first – of – its – kind petroleum oriented fest by any educational institute in the country, organized by the Society of Petroleum Engineers (SPE) IIT Kharagpur chapter. The fest aims to be an annual platform for veterans in the oil & gas industry to share knowledge and expertise with academia and young minds across nations. This initiative by dedicated students of IIT Kharagpur aims at exploring ideas for smart technologies for innovation across upstream, midstream and downstream sectors in the oil and gas industry.

PETROFIESTA 2013 envisions to tap the knowledge pool of students from premier institutions worldwide and develop their insight in an integrated manner to explore areas of growth in exploration, drilling, production and processing, refining, pipeline, transportation, petrochemicals, economics, research and development, information technology and environment management. It calls for the need to increase domestic production through sustainability and development of smart technologies, especially from unconventional sources, which has lately been an issue of interest for energy stakeholders worldwide.

With events like Petrobotics, PetroEntrepreneur, PetroDebate and Industrial Design Problems and a set of guest lectures, we hope to provide real time solutions to real time problems faced in the petroleum industry.

As rightly quoted by the UN Secretary General Ban – ki – Moon:

“We all need to be stakeholders in a sustainable future."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line is causing problem for you

```
tv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);//here tv is null
```

Change this line to

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a View inside the `Activity` and set it to tv.
Your code is wrong in two ways:

1. tv is null, when you try to access it.
2. You are tring to find your `TextView` inside your `TextView`. But you want to find the view inside the `Activity`. Right?

Change

```
tv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

to

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize textview

```
  tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and remove this

```
  tv.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
TextView Txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
```